# How can I check if my time sync is correct?

Tags: domain-controller, time-synchronization, w32time

I have updated a W2K3 settings according to the steps shown here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816042#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways2

The peers list I use is:

```
0.asia.pool.ntp.org,0x1 1.asia.pool.ntp.org,0x1 2.asia.pool.ntp.org,0x1 3.asia.pool.ntp.org,0x1
```

I did a

```
net stop w32time && net start w32time
```

to restart the service.

How do I check the settings?
How do I know it's working?

When I try the following:

```
w32tm /monitor
```

The response I get looks like the time sync goes to the local computer (the DC)

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>w32tm /monitor
    OptiDC.opti *** PDC *** [192.168.0.2]:
    ICMP: 0ms delay.
    NTP: +0.0000000s offset from OptiDC.opti
    RefID: 'LOCL' [76.79.67.76]
```

- is that what the answer should be?
- Shouldn't I see something that has one of the NTP servers from the peers list?

Comment: Look at a clock and if the time is the same It's correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use w32tm and provide the names of the computers it should contact, something like

```
w32tm /monitor /computers:0.asia.pool.ntp.org,1.asia.pool.ntp.org 
Analyzing:delayoffset from local clock
(unknown)Stratum: 2
delayoffset from local clock
Stratum: 2

Warning:
Reverse name resolution is best effort. It may not be
correct since RefID field in time packets differs across 
NTP implementations and may not be using IP addresses.


0.asia.pool.ntp.org[203.158.118.2:123]:
ICMP: 291ms 
NTP: +2.2762642s         RefID:  [0x3C45B9CB]
1.asia.pool.ntp.org[61.110.197.50:123]:
ICMP: 345ms 
NTP: +2.2593270s         RefID: time.nist.gov [192.43.244.18]
```

Comment: Thanks, but how do I know that my sync is correctly contacting the said server?

Comment: Check you event logs.